# Scrapy AttributeError: 'SoundseasySpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some date from the webpage [soundseasy.com.au](http://soundseasy.com.au), but sometimes I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'SoundseasySpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'
```

Here is my code, which use selenium web driver(self.browser instance) to fetch data from the dynamic page:

```
import scrapy
from ProductsScraper.items import ProductDataItem, ProductDataLoader
from utilities.common import MODE_SINGLE
from utilities.DynamicPageLoader import DynamicPageLoader

def start_requests(self):
    # scrape multi page data
    for page_count, url in zip(self.pages_counts, self.start_urls):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.multi_parse,
                             meta={'page_count': page_count}, 
                             dont_filter=True)

def multi_parse(self, response):
    """
    Method fetched the pages, gets the product url links and scrape it
    by calling parse_product
    """
    selector = self.get_dynamic_page(url=response.url,
                                     page_count=response.meta.get('page_count', '1'))
    product_urls = selector.xpath('//div[@class="isp_product_info"]/a/@href').extract()
    self.logger.info('{} items should be scraped from the page: {},'
                     ' scroll_count:{}'.format(len(product_urls),
                                               response.url, response.meta.get('page_count', '1')))
    for product_url in product_urls:
        # construct absolute url
        url = "https://www.{}{}".format(self.allowed_domains[0], product_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_product, dont_filter=True)

def get_dynamic_page(self, url, page_count):
    """
    Fetch dynamic page using DynamicDownloader and return selector object
    """
    # construct search page url with the page count included
    pages_url = url + '&page_num={}'.format(page_count)
    self.logger.info("get_dynamic_page: {}".format(pages_url))
    self.browser.load_page(pages_url)
    return scrapy.Selector(text=self.browser.get_html_page())
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I got the exception below:

```
  File "/home/user/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/home/user/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/failure.py", line 408, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/user/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean f
ashion: Connection lost.>]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/swampblu/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/swampblu/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 66, in process_exception
    spider=spider)
  File "/home/swampblu/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 61, in process_exception
    return self._retry(request, exception, spider)
  File "/home/swampblu/python3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 71, in _retry
    stats = spider.crawler.stats
AttributeError: 'SoundsEasySpider' object has no attribute 'crawler'
```

Comment: Could you include the import section? I have a suspicion the cause of the error might be located there.

Comment: done, but  I guess if it's a problem with import section, then it never will work, but sometimes I got some good results

Comment: error message should show which line of code makes problem - and this is why you should always put full error (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: Good point @furas. I think I was wrong about the import declarations. It could be that your selenium browser is not loading the page fast enough so that an empty or partial page is passed through. You could try to add a delay or a more specific wait instruction to ensure the page is loaded before parsing the response.

Comment: appropriate traces was added, thanks

Comment: make a class dude, `class SoundseasySpider(scrapy.Spider)` and follow proper scrapy conventions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was because of anti scraping protection. The servers were rejecting requests. I have enabled [AutoThrottle extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)